# how to coloring monitor in graphic mode in assembly

Tags: assembly

hello Why the program does not run correctly
The first runs for a short time, the display changes color
But then the color black is back
The program will draw a flag but can not correctly screen color graphics mode do

```
.model small
.stack 256
    org 100H
.data
.code
main proc 
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax          
    call graphicsmode
    call printflag              

    mov ah,00
    mov al,03
    int 10h     

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main endp

graphicsmode proc
    MOV AH,00H
    MOV AL,13H
    INT 10H 
    ret
graphicsmode endp   

printflag proc      
    ;print color green
    ;--------------------------
    mov cx,50   ;column
    mov dx,50   ;row        
L1: mov ah,0CH
    mov al,2H   ;color pixel        
    mov bh,00H
    int 10h     
    inc cx
    cmp cx,400
    jne L1

    mov cx,50
    inc dx
    cmp dx,100
    jne L1  

    ;print color white  
    ;--------------------------
    mov cx,50   ;column
    mov dx,100  ;row        
L2: mov ah,0CH
    mov al,7H   ;color pixel        
    mov bh,00H
    int 10h     
    inc cx
    cmp cx,400
    jne L2

    mov cx,50
    inc dx
    cmp dx,150
    jne L2  

    ;print color red    
    ;--------------------------
    mov cx,50   ;column
    mov dx,150  ;row        
L3: mov ah,0CH
    mov al,4H   ;color pixel        
    mov bh,00H
    int 10h     
    inc cx
    cmp cx,400
    jne L3

    mov cx,50
    inc dx
    cmp dx,200
    jne L3  
    ret
printflag endp

end main
```

Comment: I'm sure you realize that "int 21h" and "int 10h" are obsolete DOS/BIOS calls.  No modern OS supports them ... except via DOS prompt emulation.
SUGGESTIONS: 1) Step through your code under your favorite assembly debugger ("gdb" is a good choice on many platforms) and verify your code is correct.  2) Failing all else, blame your DOS prompt emulator

Comment: Mode 13h is only 320x200 and you're trying to draw lines outside that range. Also the first thing you do after draw the flag is switch back to text mode which will erase what you've drawn. So you can only see it while its being drawn, once its finished drawing it will immediately erase it.

Answer (score 1):

For mode 0x13 you can fill the screen with a `rep stosw" instruction like this:

```
    ;al = colour to use

    mov bx,0xA000
    mov es,bx
    mov cx,320*200/2
    mov di,0
    cld
    mov ah,al
    rep stosw
```

If you do one pixel at a time, then you'd need to calculate "address = y*320+x" 64000 times, which is incredibly slow and pointless. It also means that you write one byte at a time, and that adds up to 64000 transfers across a PCI bus (where you could halve the number of transfers by doing 2 bytes at a time, or do 4 bytes at a time).

Using the BIOS function is far worse. It begins with an interrupt (which is slow) then has a whole bunch of branches to figure out which function you want, then has another bunch of branches to figure out which video mode you're using, and after all that it has all the problems of "one pixel at a time" (mentioned above).

Basically; your code has 2 problems - it needs to be redesigned/rewritten, and it has bugs. If you find and fix the bugs it'd still need to be redesigned/rewritten; so there's no point finding and fixing the bugs.

Comment: Your answer has 3 little problems! We use `cld` to correctly execute this string primitive. Using `stosw` implies halving the counter. Having **640000** address calculations is a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @user3144770: D'oh - you're right. I fixed the bugs and got rid of the erroneous extra zero on 64000 :-)